# How to get ride of duplicate and useless URL from /component/contact

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4

I try to use the form from Joomla, but seems there are strange downsides…

If I setup a contact form, from `Components > Contacts`, and put this `Contact Component` inside a `Menu`, I can access the "contact page" form from all these URL:

1. `/index.php?option=com_contact&view=contact&id=1`
2. `/component/contact?view=contact&id=1:contact`
3. `/contact`

where the first ones return to the same path, but the last one is somehow "independent", with different meta tags…, but not so much (if I remove the contact component, I get a 404 error).

More strange, I have the following useless URL that seems to act like a category page:

- `/component/contact`

Is there a way to get ride of all these page, without recourse to `.htaccess`?